# Not able to figure out how to compile kernel code on GPU instead of CPU using OpenCL

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I'm a beginner in coding in OpenCL. I was trying to compile some sample code I got off the internet on my GPU using OpenCL. Although I'm using `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU` tag, the kernel code is still getting compiled in the CPU, as shown by the task manager. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XFTF.jpg).
Please guide me in this regard

```
    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
    //printf("no of devices %d", ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);
```

Comment: You'll need to be a bit clearer in your question. (1) The OpenCL **compiler** will normally always run on the CPU. It's the **kernel** that will run on the GPU. (2) Your process won't suddenly have 0% CPU utilisation just because you are running some OpenCL kernels on the GPU. Please clarify what you are measuring, and what you are expecting.

Comment: kernel function is there but my kernel is using cpu and not my gpu. My GPU is at 0% utilisation, i want it to run the kernel function.

Comment: What kind of kernel is this? If it’s trivial, you might just be spending lots of time moving data back and forth, and your implementation might not be counting that towards “GPU utilisation”. Also, does the kernel run for long enough to make a dent in the stats?